# C++ Queue not removing elements properly from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having a problem with a queue I have set up in c++. I have the code set up and most of it is working. but for some reason when I remove one element from my array and try to display it, I am only shown one element of the array in the middle ( the array is only a size of 3 ). When i add another to it, that works fine, but after that if i try to remove elements or add, nothing is displayed to show that anything was removed or added. 
Can anyone help me with getting this how it should be? I have added the code so that you can see how I have it set up.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 3;

class Queue
{
private:
    char ship;
    string arr[MAX];
    int head;
    int tail;


public:

Queue()
{
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}

void Add(string ship)
{   
    arr[tail++] = ship; 
}

void Remove()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ship ID: " << arr[head] << " has been removed from the queue!" 
<< endl;
    arr->erase(head);
    //head++;
    tail--;
}


void display()
{

    for (int i = head; i < tail; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

bool IsEmpty()
{
    if (tail-head == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
bool IsFull()
{
    if (tail-head == MAX)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
Queue q;
string ship;

q.Add(ship = "K349, 42, 8");
q.Add(ship = "K653, 22, 6");
q.Add(ship = "D994, 60, 10");

if (q.IsEmpty())
{
    cout << "Queue is empty!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Queue is not empty!" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

q.display();
q.Remove();
q.display();

system("pause");

q.Add(ship = "F777, 26, 7");

q.display();


    q.Remove();
    q.Remove();
    q.Remove();


if (q.IsEmpty())
{
    cout << "Queue is empty!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Queue is not empty!" << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from `arr->erase(head);` ? (it is indeed `arr[0].erase(head);`)

Comment: Since when did C Style arrays get member functions? (Be clearer with erase)

Comment: @ArnavBorborah He's dereferencing the array (getting the first element) and calling `erase` on it. The elements are strings, so this is surprisingly legal: `arr[0].erase(head);`

Comment: Your `ship = ` is useless in `q.Add(ship = "K349, 42, 8");`.

Comment: `Remove` is downright broken. Why does `tail` change when the `head` is erased? If it's because you couldn't make it work the right way on a C-style array, you should reconsider your container design.

Comment: All of your issues are likely because your ring buffer's size is 3 and you're trying to insert 3 elements. At this point, `head == tail` (if the implementation is correct) and you'll think your list is empty. The max amount of elements you can store like this should be the size of the ring buffer - 1 and you should prevent more from being added in the member functions

Comment: Consider adding diagnostic output statements ... start with Add()